# What do I do about: this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am working on integrating micode's open source compass into an app I am making. I am wondering how I can fix this here permission error when I clearly have it stated in my manifest with the correct spelling. Its still coming up that I need that permission.

This is puzzling me...

```
11-03 13:53:58.241: E/AndroidRuntime(8975): Caused by: \
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: registerReceiver from \
    net.micode.compass asks to run as user -1 but is calling from user 0; this \
    requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
```

Comment: Raghav has right.. This is a signature level permission, you cannot use it in your app unless it has the same signature of the system, i.e., you have built the system yourself and you have signed it with your own key. BTW, could you show me which exact piece of code that produced this exception? I am just curious..

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL` is a signature level permission. Your app will not be able to use it until and unless it has the same signature as the system.

Comment: Which is not something you can achieve unless you either are the creator or the system build, or collaborating with them such that they are willing to sign your apk with their certificate.  In other words, this is off limits for most developers.

Comment: so what to do? why is this happening?

Comment: How do I add this permission...? is this the right way? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" />

Comment: Please check this link, might be helpfull https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28134128/android-permission-interact-across-users-full/45057190#45057190

Answer (score 8):

I had a same problem and i did **project -> clean**. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

I know there is already an accepted answer but for some reason its not working (or no longer working) on my part.

This error happened to me on Android SDK version 19 and lower, because of NDK that was part of my app.

I just deleted few codes that are connected with NDK codes at the Android Manifests file.

Answer (score 0):

I disabled autofill and project started to work normally. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45731372/disabling-android-o-auto-fill-service-for-an-application?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Just add this code to your app :

```
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        window.decorView.importantForAutofill = 
        View.IMPORTANT_FOR_AUTOFILL_NO_EXCLUDE_DESCENDANTS;
    }
```