# Fragment calling view method

Tags: android, android-fragments, custom-view

I have a fragment with a custom view in it. This custom view is a Sudokuboard.

SInce the view needs the starting numbers my thought was to give this from the fragment onCreate using a view method i added ( public void add_numbers(String)  )

But when I call this method in the fragment onCreate the app crashes with android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL exception.

Anyone got any ideas what I'm doing wrong here ?

Code below is the fragments onCreate method. The strings and sudokuview is declaed at the very top.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_game, container, false);

    // Get arguments
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    boardID = args.getString("BoardID");
    boardNumbersOriginal = args.getString("boardNumbers");
    boardSolution = args.getString("BoardSolution");

    sudokuView = (SudokuView) view.findViewById(R.id.sudokuview);

    sudokuView.setBoardNumbers(boardNumbersOriginal);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to modify someone else's application code? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19756727/what-do-i-do-about-this-requires-android-permission-interact-across-users-full

Comment: Not intentionally :) Not sure how I could be trying something "illegal" here. I've written the view and it's methods, so they are "mine". If I simply remove the sudokuview = (Sudo...) and the method call it works and the view is shown as expected,.

Comment: Which code cause the crash?  How should I know where "add_numbers" is?

Comment: the metodcall seems to be the cause of the crash. add_number ?

Comment: Show the exception stacktrace. That's the most important thing....